# Why do i get the same result even with different byteorder?

Tags: python

This is when we convert numbers to bytes :

```
print(int.to_bytes(65, length=1, byteorder='big')) #this converts numbers to characters
```

result:

```
A
```

why do i see the same result even if i used different byteorder ?

```
print(int.from_bytes(b'A', byteorder='big', signed=True))
print(int.from_bytes(b'A', byteorder='little', signed=True))
```

result:

```
65
65
```

Comment: the result should be b'8' in the little big endian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because one char ('A') is stored in a single byte. The change of order big/little is visible with many bytes. Tested with 2 **different** bytes:

```
>>> print(int.from_bytes(b'AB', byteorder='big', signed=True))
16706
>>> print(int.from_bytes(b'AB', byteorder='little', signed=True))
16961
```

See [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes)

Comment: why is it 16706 ??? how is it calculating it ?

Comment: This is how the number look like in binary:

>>> bin(int.from_bytes(b'A', byteorder='big', signed=True))
'0b1000001'
>>> bin(int.from_bytes(b'B', byteorder='big', signed=True))
'0b1000010'
>>> bin(int.from_bytes(b'AB', byteorder='big', signed=True))
'0b100000101000010'
>>> bin(int.from_bytes(b'AB', byteorder='little', signed=True))
'0b100001001000001'

If you transform binary numbers to decimal you get those numbers. Try online [link](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-decimal.html)

Comment: but i tried to do some conversions and i didn't get that number

Comment: Also note - that  : `b'AB', byteorder='big'` should give you the same result as `b'BA', byteorder='little'`

Comment: that is literally right i have just tried that